# How can I configure the svelte formater to respect line breaks in HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte-3

I have the following svelte file:

```
<script>
  import { text } from 'svelte/internal';
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  form {
    label, input {
      font-weight: 800;
    }
  }
</style>

<form>
  <label for="list">List</label>
  <input type="text" id="list" />
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
```

When I use shift + alt + f on this file this is my output:

```
<script>
  import { text } from 'svelte/internal';
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  form {
    label,
    input {
      font-weight: 800;
    }
  }
</style>

<form><label for="list">List</label> <input type="text" id="list" /> <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" /></form>
```

So now my label, input in the CSS is on separate lines, while my HTML is all in one line. This is the exact opposite of what I want.

How can I set up vscode to format this file correctly?

Comment: There is no formatter bundled with Svelte, this is due to some other formatter you have installed like prettier.

Comment: https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte is bundled with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode

Comment: @StephaneVanraes I'm really not interested in what plugin is doing it now.  I'm asking what plugin / setting I need to get it formatted correctly